# What is the point of the following capacitors?

Tags: differential, high-speed, probe

Sorry if this question is dumb, I'm still a student...

Anyways, I was looking at a [design](https://circuitcellar.com/research-design-hub/high-voltage-differential-probe/) of a high voltage differential probe on the web and was wondering what is the purpose of the capacitors seen in C1~C8, as well as C14~C15.

I'd assume that the capacitors C9~C12 are meant to be used to achieve a low pass filter in conjunction with R1~R8, and that R18 is meant to be used to control the current feedback on the op-amps' gain. (Is there a reason the four resistors on R18 are in one package? and that two resistors are connected in parallel? why not just a 0.5k resistor?)

However I don't understand what is being achieved by placing these capacitors (C1~C8,C14~C15) in parallel with a resistor in the signal path. Is there a formula that describes the signal after going through the circuit?

…I looked up information on similar circuitry on google and only found one website saying that it is a ["pre-emphasis" circuit](http://www.repeater-builder.com/tech-info/pdemph-post.html). (is it a high-pass filter?)

One last question that I have is how does the attenuation selection circuitry seen near SW18 works. Isn't U1A and U2A amplifying two different signals?

Also, does anyone have resources for low voltage differential probe designs? If so, it's greatly appreciated.

[image: Input stage of high voltage differential probe.]

Comment: https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/alm1k/circuits1/alm-cir-voltage-divider

Answer (score 2):

> What is the point of the following capacitors?

The designer gave his reasons for the capacitors in [the document you linked.](https://circuitcellar.com/research-design-hub/high-voltage-differential-probe/)

> ...what about the AC behavior? The buffer op amps will have a small but finite input capacitance, as will the protection diodes. This capacitance, with the 4 MΩ input resistance, forms a low-pass filter that will severely attenuate high-frequency signals. According to the datasheets, this combined capacitance of the op amp and protection diodes will be on the order of 4.3 pF. Not much, you might say. But the corner frequency of this low-pass filter will be under 10 kHz.

> The answer, of course, is to add some frequency compensation capacitance across the 4 MΩ resistors. The impedance of this and the parasitic capacitance should be in the same ratio as the resistances in the voltage divider. In our case, the compensation capacitors should be 199 times smaller than 4.3 pF. Obviously, this is not practical, so we have to tackle this problem from the other direction. First, let’s choose a reasonable compensation capacitance and calculate the other capacitance.

> I chose to use a string of four 10 pF, 500 V, 5%, 1206 SMT capacitors in series. This gives us a compensation capacitance of 2.5 pF and will handle input voltages to 2 kV, comfortably exceeding our ±800 V input limit defined by the resistors. For proper frequency compensation we now need a total capacitance at the input to the buffer op amps of 497.5 pF. In practice, this is made up by the parallel combination of the op amp and diode input capacitance, two fixed capacitors (C9/C10 and C11/C12) and a trimmer capacitor. The trimmer provides a range of adjustment of 461 pF to 524 pF to allow for component tolerances and layout differences. The total capacitance seen at the input terminals is nominally 2.5 pF, since the compensation capacitors will dominate.

That is, the capacitors are there to raise the bandwidth of the amplifier. The bandwidth of the amplifier needs to be raised because the combination of high resistances and stray capacitances forms a low pass filter. Without these capacitors, the designer estimated that the bandwidth would be less than 10 kHz.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the requirement to tolerate a high input voltage the input resistors R1-R4 and R5-R8 are divided into multiple resistors rather than each being a single.

The Bottom end of the input potential divider is R9A, R9B, R10, and VR1 on the positive side and R9C, R9D, R11, and Vr1 on the negative side.

Every physical resistor will have stray capacitance, of the order of a few tenths of a pF, that will affect its effective impedance at higher frequencies. To counteract that each resistor is paralleled with a capacitor that is much larger than its parasitic capacitance but not so large that it compromises the performance of the circuit.

In order to achieve a flat frequency response, the bottom end of the potential divider is paralleled with a capacitor such that the time constant of C9, C10 and VC1 in parallel with R9A, R9B, R10, and VR1 is th esame as the time constant of the input resistor and capacitor combination R1 etc. The C9, C10 etc is not a low pass filter but to achieve a flat frequency response.

The four sections of R18 could have been two individual resistors but the designer was probably attempting to achieve better matching between the two sides than possible with separate components.

This whole circuit is a differential probe whose goal is to amplify the difference between the input signals at J1 and J2 and not be affected by any common-mode level at that point. It is also the objective to have as flat a frequency response as possible so that the waveform of any signals at the input is preserved faithfully.

Answer (score 0):

If a divider has capacitance across only part of the divider chain then it will give a different division ratio at difference frequencies. To produce a flat frequency response the rc time constant of all the elements of the divider must match.

Capacitance is everywhere, you can't get rid of it, the best you can do is hope to manage it. Generally this means making the deliberately engineered capacitance significantly larger than the stray capacitance.

The core of the divider chain has a resistance of about 40.3 Kohm and a deliberate capacitance adjustable from about 230pF to 260pF which if there was no stray capacitance would give a time constant of about 9.3 to 10.47 microseconds.

The outboard parts of the divider chain have a resistance of 1 megohm and a capacitance of 10pF which assuming there is no stray capacitance gives a time constant of 10 microseconds.

Note that the probe you linked is not isolated. It *will* leak some current from the input circuit to the output ground.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I got the gist of it. However, I don't understand why the value of C9~C10, and VC1 is significantly larger than the C1~C4. Since C1~C4 would add up to be around 2.5pF, shouldn't we pick value of C9 and C10 to be something similar to that to get a flat response?

Comment: @ShaunG. - The time constant of the upper section and the lower section must be the same. Or to put it another way the division ratio of the capacitors must be the same as the resistors.

Comment: The r is much lower in the center section so the c must be higher to get the same time constant. Another way to think of this is to remember that capacitive reactance is proportional to the inverse of capacitance.